# What is the purpose of the AmplifyDataStore DynamoDB table?

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, aws-amplify, aws-amplify-cli

## Context

When using **AWS Amplify JS**, and specifically the `DataStore` part of the SDK, the models that you specify in your `schema.graphql` each get an associated DynamoDB table:

#### `schema.graphql`

```
type Blog @model {
  id: ID!
  name: String!
  posts: [Post] @connection(name: "BlogPosts")
}
type Post @model {
  id: ID!
  title: String!
  blog: Blog @connection(name: "BlogPosts")
  comments: [Comment] @connection(name: "PostComments")
}
type Comment @model {
  id: ID!
  content: String
  post: Post @connection(name: "PostComments")
}
```

This corresponds to 4 DynamoDB tables that get created in AWS

- `Blog-somerandomstring-dev` — (makes sense)
- `Post-somerandomstring-dev` — (makes sense)
- `Comment-somerandomstring-dev` — (makes sense)
- `AmplifyDataStore-somerandomstring-dev` — (where does this table come from?)

## Question

Given the above, what is the explanation behind, and/or function of this extra table (`AmplifyDataStore-somerandomstring-dev`)?

Answer (score 0):

## Answer

This extra table, not created by any particular `@model` in your Amplify Graphql schema is called the **[Delta Sync Table](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/appsync/latest/devguide/conflict-detection-and-sync.html#delta-sync-table)** and its purpose to help with *Conflict Detection and Sync*

This may not mean much, but the rest of the [doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/appsync/latest/devguide/conflict-detection-and-sync.html) explains how Amplify/AppSync go about conflict resolution for your data.